# socket 'listen' error in C

Tags: sockets, server, irc

i'm trying to create server with TCP IP protocol

But it doesn't accept connection, or may be because of listen

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void error(char *msg)
{
perror(msg);
exit(1);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd,newsockfd,num_port,serveur_T;
    socklen_t client_T;
    char buffer[200];
    struct sockaddr_in adr_serveur, adr_client;
    int n;


    if (argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "nombre d'arguments est insuffisant\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    sockfd=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0)
    {
        error("erreur de creation de socket");
    }

    serveur_T=sizeof(adr_serveur);
    bzero((char*)&adr_serveur, serveur_T);
    num_port=atoi(argv[1]);

    adr_serveur.sin_family=AF_INET;
    adr_serveur.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;
    adr_serveur.sin_port=htons(num_port);

    serveur_T=sizeof(adr_serveur);
    if (bind ( sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &adr_serveur,serveur_T)<0)
    {
        error(" Erreur de binding");
    }

    listen (sockfd,5);
    client_T= sizeof(adr_client);
    newsockfd= accept(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &adr_client,&client_T);

    if ( newsockfd<0)
    {
        error("Erreur socket accept");
    }
    bzero(buffer, 200);



return 0;}
```

When I execute server I got this error

```
Erreur socket accept: Operation not supported
```

Second question: Can I use an IRC client and connect it to my server ? In my school we have Linux servers so I'm wondering if I can use them as a hostname ?
Thanks

Comment: a) Check the return value of `listen()`, it's probably failing. b) Which port are you binding to? Most modern operating systems require root (or equivalent) privileges to bind to reserved ports (ports < 1024).

Comment: You have asked two separate questions.  The IRC question should be posted as a separate question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> i'm trying to create server with TCP IP protocol

You have created a `SOCK_DGRAM` (UDP) socket, not a `SOCK_STREAM` (TCP) socket.  You cannot call `listen()` or `accept()` on a UDP socket, only on a TCP socket.  `listen()` is reporting an `EOPNOTSUPP` error:

[listen(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/listen)

> **EOPNOTSUPP**
>   The socket is not of a type that supports the **listen()** operation.

You are ignoring that error, and then `accept()` is reporting the same error:

[accept(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/accept)

> **EOPNOTSUPP**
>   The referenced socket is not of type **SOCK_STREAM**.

There are no connections in UDP, so there is nothing to accept.  Once you have bound a UDP socket to a port, you can start calling `recvfrom()` and `sendto()` on it.

In order to connect an IRC client to this server code, you need to change the socket type to `SOCK_STREAM`.  IRC runs on TCP, not on UDP.

Comment: Thank you , It works.

I want to know how to know the local hostname, because I want to join this server using irssi. Is it possible?

Comment: You don't need the actual hostname when connecting locally, just connect to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: I run the server with port 6000 and the irssi and put /JOIN 127.0.0.1 6000 but  my resuest is denied : "Not connected to server.

Comment: `/JOIN` is an IRC command to enter an IRC channel *AFTER* you have connected to an IRC server. You have to connect to `127.0.0.1:6000` first then `JOIN` a channel. But your server does not implement the IRC protocol yet, you don't even have basic TCP working yet.  Forget about IRC until you understand the basics of TCP first.

Comment: Ok I see more clearly.. But firstly I would try to connect a client to it , before starting coding chating section.. Its a school work so  we are not asked to have a perfect IRC server. So it I understand an IRC client could not connect to my server by giving server name and port? In this case can you give me some help to know what should I add so that the client can connect to my server ? Thanks